# convert latitude and longitude values from dms to dd in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I have `latitude` and `longitude` values in `DegreesMinutesSeconds(DMS)`
like `17264496N,78223862E`.

I need to convert to `DecimalDegrees(DD)` like `17.8688,078.12547`.

Is there any way to convert from dms to dd.

In Google search i found only dms conversion for values which have separate columns by **degrees**, **Minutes**, **Seconds**  like degrees 17, minutes 26, seconds 44.

Comment: you will have to split the string and apply to a function like this: (or build the split into the function) http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/sql_server_blog/189/cogo-convert-degrees-minutes-and-seconds-values-to-decimal-degrees

Comment: here degrees minutes and seconds are seperated but in my case itsn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,We must first split the dms value into degrees,minutes and seconds in the following way.
All you have to do is 
Step1:Create function that takes dms latitude value as parameter.
Step2:Now the function returns decimal degree value

```
     ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLatitudeConversionFromDMSToDD] 

  (
@LatitudeInDMS NVARCHAR(100)
  )
 Returns FLOAT
 As

Begin
            Declare @FirstTwoCharForStartLat nvarchar(100),@CharElimForStartLat          
             nvarchar(100), @RemCharForStartLat nvarchar(100),
            @CharElimcountForStartLat float, @DegreetodecimalcalcForStartLat float

            select @FirstTwoCharForStartLat= LEFT(@LatitudeInDMS,2)
            select @CharElimForStartLat=LEFT(@LatitudeInDMS,LEN(@LatitudeInDMS)-1)
            select @RemCharForStartLat=RIGHT(@CharElimForStartLat,6)
            select @CharElimcountForStartLat=((CAST(@RemCharForStartLat as    
            float))/600000) 
            select @DegreetodecimalcalcForStartLat=(cast(@FirstTwoCharForStartLat as
            float))+@CharElimcountForStartLat 


   Return @DegreetodecimalcalcForStartLat

 END

      --select dbo.GetLatitudeConversionFromDMSToDD('17264496N')
      --The output is:17.4408266666667
```